# Incompatible block pointer types in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I am getting this error "Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(void)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(NSTimer * _Nonnull __strong)'" in this line "[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3/self.MAX repeats:YES block:^{".

Thanks in advance.

```
self.progressTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3/self.MAX repeats:YES block:^{
        self.progressRight.constant = self.progressRight.constant + 1.0;
        if (self.progressRight.constant >= self.MAX) {
            self.ENOUGH = YES;
            self.PANIC = NO;
            [self.progressTimer invalidate];
            [self submit];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Unrelated, I'd suggest using `weakSelf` pattern, i.e., before creating the timer, create `typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self`, and then reference `weakSelf` inside that block rather than `self`. Otherwise you're introducing what is effectively a strong reference cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block signature is wrong.

To fix this kind of issue yourself

- Comment out the entire method.
- Retype the first characters and use code completion.
- Select the desired method.

The compiler will suggest

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3/self.MAX repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
    // code
}];
```

That's what the error message says:

- Expected type `(^ _Nonnull)(NSTimer * _Nonnull __strong)`
- Given type `'void (^)(void)`

Comment: app is crashing when it comes this line of code. timer is coming nil.